# Rendering partial view resulting in error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

rails 3.2
   Ruby 2.1.5

I am trying to have a single form for a ticket, that includes a number of sections.

One of the sectios is called customer_info

In the app/views/tickets/show.html.slim, I have:

```
= render 'tickets/sections/customer_info', locals: { customer_info: CustomerInfo.new, ticket: @ticket }
```

and in my app/views/tickets/sections/_customer_info.html.slim, I have:

```
= form_for customer_info do |f|
  - f.hidden_field :ticket_id, :value => ticket.id
  .form-horizontal-column.customer-info
    .form-group
      = f.label :pre_tax_total
      = f.text_field :pre_tax_total, maxlength: 50
    .form-group
      = f.label :post_tax_total
      = f.text_field :post_tax_total, maxlength: 50
   .actions = f.submit 'Save'
  .clear
```

When the app attempts to render the customer_info form, I get the following error message:

```
undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class
```

When it hits the first line in the form:

```
= form_for customer_info do |f|
```

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: seems like `customer_info` is nil

Comment: Yes, it is nil. You get a nil when you call the controller new action. My question here is how do I call a partial view for another controller action from a view for one controller. In this case, I am in the form view of the tickets controller, and I want to render a view for the new action of the CustomerInfo controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change the render code from

```
= render 'tickets/sections/customer_info', locals: { customer_info: CustomerInfo.new, ticket: @ticket }
```

to

```
= render partial: 'tickets/sections/customer_info', locals: { customer_info: CustomerInfo.new, ticket: @ticket }
```

Always remember to add `partial` if `locals` is used.

Comment: I did that and now I get: undefined method `customer_info_path' for #<#<Class:0x000000088fc3e0>:0x007f1f9cef0ca0>

Comment: Change the code to the old syntax:

{ :customer_info => CustomerInfo.new, :ticket => @ticket }

And check where are you calling model_name.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "where are you calling model_name". The syntax you suggested produces the same results

Comment: It comes from the form helper, because you create a new CustomerInfo object, the form helper will use the `customer_info_path` as the default url used in form. You should make sure there is a `customer_info_path` in your routes.

Comment: You can test the form is working or not without using partial first, if it is ok, it should be ok as well when moving form to a partial.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this

```
= render 'tickets/sections/customer_info', locals: { ticket: @ticket }
```

And

```
= form_for CustomerInfo.new do |f|
  - f.hidden_field :ticket_id, :value => ticket.id
  .form-horizontal-column.customer-info
    .form-group
      = f.label :pre_tax_total
      = f.text_field :pre_tax_total, maxlength: 50
    .form-group
      = f.label :post_tax_total
      = f.text_field :post_tax_total, maxlength: 50
   .actions = f.submit 'Save'
  .clear
```

Comment: This does not change anything. I am still getting the undefined method `customer_info_path' for #<#<Class:0x000000088fc3e0>:0x007f1f9cef0ca0> error